# How can I make a variable for each person in my discord server with python?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a game for my discord server, and I need every member of the discord server to have their own number of coins. Therefore, I need every member of my discord server to have their own variable for their coins. If anyone knows how I could do this that would be a huge help! Thanks.

Comment: What you are looking for is called a `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using a dictionary where the keys might be the usernames of each player and values are the number of coins that user has.

Say you have a list of usernames called usernames and each player initially has 10 coins,
The code would be something similar to this:

```
usernames = ['jason', 'jack', 'hunter']
coins = 10
players = {}
for user in usernames:
    players[user] = 10
print(players)
```

Output would be this:

```
{'jason': 10, 'jack': 10, 'hunter': 10}
```

Comment: Got that, but what if a new member joins?

Comment: You'll add this new user to the dictionary using this line of code ```players[key] = number_of_coins``` where the key is the username of the newly joined member and assuming that players is the name of the dictionary you created

Comment: I'd recommend using a JSON file to store a list of all of the members and their coins. It has the same syntax as Python dictionaries, but in it's own file.